# How to fetch a .txt file from a different domain from server side javascript and get it client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm trying to fetch a .txt file from a webserver on a different domain which has no CORS or webservices. I think I need to do it on server side with Node.js and JQuery, but I'm not sure where to start. I am currently Node and JQuery challenged.

The file resides here http://epec.saw.usace.army.mil/dsskerr.txt

Comment: This is how you do it: http://gyazo.com/5d6e71efcd53d47c5a5bd9d4345cd4fe. AJAX request to your server nodejs script. The script makes another request to other server to load text file. You domain node app responds to AJAX request with loaded content.

Comment: @dfsq please dont post a link to an image which is an answer in a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you will need to write a little Node app server side.

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    request = require("request");

var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port);

app.get("/data", function (req, res) {
    request.get("http://epec.saw.usace.army.mil/dsskerr.txt").pipe(res);
});
```

On the client side you could do the following.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple app to fetch a txt file</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>simple app to fetch a txt file through a node server to get around CORS</h2>
        <div class="data"> </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $.get("/data", function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $(".data").append(data);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a full git repo with the solution.  https://github.com/jsloyer/node-fetch-txt-file.

Additionally you can deploy the solution to Bluemix by clicking the button below.
[image: Deploy to Bluemix]